# Ansible: Check if service is listening on a specific port

Tags: linux, ansible

How would you go about using Ansible to confirm whether a service is running on a specific port?

For example:

- Is Apache running on port 80?
- Is MySQL listening on port 3912?
- Is Tomcat listening on port 8080?

I understand that there are the `service` and `wait_for` commands, which individually check if a service is running and if a port is in use - but I've not found anything so far to check if a particular service is listening on a particular port. `service` and `wait_for` will indicate there's a service and a port, but there's no guarantee that the port is taken by that particular service - it could be taken by anything. `wait_for`, as I understand it, simply checks if it's being used.

There is a `regex_search` parameter on `wait_for` which mentions searching in a socket connection for a particular string, but as I understand it this is simply reading any information that comes down that socket rather than having any access to what is sending that information.

How can we go about this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is probably too broad according to the [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of this website. You can write your own module that combine both, or you can just combine them in a playbook (what is wrong with doing it in 2 steps?). In order to get better answers try to improve the question showing what you have tried and what is the problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @PauloScardine. I can't say I feel this question is too broad, given it's trying to do something specific in Ansible, but I can understand why you would see it that way. I will update the question to indicate the issue with using those two commands.

Comment: It is a fair question, only not suited for this site because there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. AFAIK there is no built-in module to do what you want so I guess you would have to write your own ansible module or use an external shell script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of interpreting your question, so I'm going to try to answer them both:

### Verifying a network service

If your goal is to verify that a particular port is serving a particular application protocol, I would check this by running an appropriate client.

- For checking Apache and Tomcat, I would `GET` a specific url and check the result code.  For example:

  ```
  - name: check if apache is running
    command: curl -sf http://webserver/check_url
  ```

  And similarly for Tomcat.
- For checking MySQL, I would use the MySQL client:

  ```
  - name: check if mysql is running
    command: mysql -h dbhost -P dbport -e 'select 1'
  ```

### Verifying what process owns a socket

If you actually wanted to see what *process* was holding a particular port open, I guess you could combine `ss` and `grep`, but that seems weird and unnecessary.  Something like:

```
    - name: check if httpd has port 80 open
      shell: ss -tp state listening sport = :80 | grep httpd
```

If you want to check a particular process id, you could so something similar with `lsof`:

```
    - name: check that pid {{apache_pid}} is listening on port 80
      shell: lsof -p 1036 -P | grep 'TCP \*:80'
```

But again, I don't necessarily find these options particularly useful.  The service checks in the earlier section seem to be more appropriate.

Comment: Please be very careful with the shell module. As the Ansible documentation says, there are a lot of security risks you are taking if you use it, see http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html
For that reason the solution below from Paulo https://stackoverflow.com/a/28610981/3702902 might be a better approach because it avoids the shell module

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are looking at this problem with a wrong approach.
You would use configuration management systems(like Ansible) to make changes to your system, but you would use something like `Serverspec` to ensure that correct processes are listening on correct ports.
Furthermore, your playbooks should be constructed in such a way that you are never in an ambiguous situation where different services could be listening on the same ports.

Comment: This is a very good comment but it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @PauloScardine and that's why it deserves a down vote?

Comment: Since it is not an answer it really deserves to be flagged for deletion - but why are you asking anyway?

Comment: I disagree that this is a comment and not an answer. I posted it as an answer because this is what I intended it to be. It is up to OP to decide if it's acceptable to their question.

Comment: So don't worry, it will be accepted and/or get upvoted by the community and I will owe you an apology.

Comment: Indeed this should be the way to do it. Sometimes its best not to give people what they ask for but rather what they need.

Comment: *Configuring* a service to use a port, and then *verifying* that it is actually functional on that port are both useful things to do. There are lots of unexpected things that can go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in module in ansible that will verify a combination of a port and a service.  What you will likely need to do is figure out an appropriate call to a command like netstat and invoke that via the [command](http://docs.ansible.com/command_module.html) or [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html) modules.  For example on a linux box the following command will show you what process is listening on port 80:

```
$ netstat -tunlp | grep ":80 " | sed -e 's/.*\///'
httpd
```

So from Ansible you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
- name: Get service on port 80
  shell: netstat -tunlp | grep ":80 " | sed -e 's/.*\///'
  register: results

- name: See what netstat returned
  debug: var=results
```

If you want to be a bit fancier you could write a shell script that encapsulates the netstat call and does some more detailed parsing/validation of the output before returning the results to ansible.  But then you'd need to install that script prior to invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no built-in module that does this. Probably it is trivial to do it using the shell module or writing a small shell command that performs all checks.

You can use the `fuser` command to check what process is listening at a given TCP port:

```
$ sudo fuser -n tcp 80
80/tcp:              20031 20080 20081
```

You can use `ps` to see the name of the process:

```
$ ps hp 20031,20080,20081 -o comm
apache2
apache2
apache2
```

Combining everything:

```
$ ps hp `fuser -n tcp 80 2> /dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 2` -o comm
apache2

$ ps hp `fuser -n tcp 80 2> /dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 2` -o comm | grep apache2 -q
$ echo $?  # should be 0 if apache2 is listening on port 80
0
```

Comment: While this answer is missing the details of implementing this in Ansible tasks, I prefer this solution to the (chosen) solution above because with fuser you can take advantage of the "command" module in Ansible and do not have to use the "shell" module - which should be avoided due to security concerns if possible.