# If a server has nginx and apache installed, how do I find out which one it uses for its website?

Tags: apache, nginx, scripting, ansible

We have a lot of servers and vhosts and some of them use nignx, some httpd or apache for their domains. I want to write an ansible script that pulls the information out on what web server the vhost uses for its site, the problem is that a lot of them have all 3 web servers installed but only one is actually used for the site to run (others might have an active status).

I mean, I don't even know where to begin. A simple example of a bash script would be nice that accurately outputs the web server of the vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: "`If a server has nginx and apache installed, how do I find out which one is used for the website?`"

A: Given a "website" we know the IP address and port. Then the question is: What daemon is running at www_ip host and www_port?

Let's use `lsof` and print the first item on the list. The play below (as an example nginx is listening at port 8080)

```
- hosts: www_ip
  vars:
    www_port: 8080
  tasks:
    - shell: "lsof -i :{{ www_port }}|
              grep LISTEN|
              cut -d ' ' -f 1"
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines|first }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [www_ip] => {
    "msg": "nginx"
}
```

Notes

- This solution works with Linux.
- A lot of other ideas and comments can be found in [Ansible: Check if service is listening on a specific port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606876/ansible-check-if-service-is-listening-on-a-specific-port)

Comment: ```
- hosts: vm2
  vars:
    www_port: 80
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - shell: "lsof -i :{{ www_port }} | grep LISTEN | cut -d ' ' -f 1"
      register: result
    - debug: msg="{{ result.stdout_lines|first }}"
```
this worked for me, I don't know why you used port 8080

Comment: I used port 8080 to illustrate the possibility only. You are right http default port is 80.

Answer (score 3):

how about checking the ports 80 or 443 which process is using them:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep '0.0.0.0:80' | awk '{print $7}'
```

and for port 443:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep '0.0.0.0:443' | awk '{print $7}'
```

The output will be one of those lines:

```
xx/httpd # for apache
xx/nginx # for nginx
```

And you can write an ansible task to run this cmd

Comment: I do like this way of thinking!

Comment: Yeah, that should work. But do I have to check both ports?

Comment: depends if you use https or not, but you can use both commands, if nothing listening to port 443 , it will not print anything.

Comment: Just `sudo netstat -ntlp` helped me

Comment: You can use awk to do the filtering, and maybe you should add a word-boundary delimiter after the port. Also, you might wat/need to list IPv6: `sudo netstat -ntlp | awk '$4 ~ /(0.0.0.0|::):(80|443)\>/ { print $7 }'`